# React state fetching value from localStorage is undefined even though console logging 'localStorage.getItems("items")' returns valid string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, local-storage

I am building a Tenzies game and would like to implement a functionality that stores the number of previous rolls of the dice a user has to the localStorage and I already have a feature that renders the number of current rolls to the UI.

What I initially did was get a count that increases when the roll button is pressed. The `rollCount` saves the number of rolls. `prevRollCount` stores the previous count which should be the value of `rollCount`. The issue is the `storeRoll` which console logs the value I intended first then almost immediately logs undefined after setting the `storeRoll` to zero on page refresh. The `undefined` is logged until there is a win. Then the value of `storeRoll` updates to the previous roll count as intended but on subsequent gameplay without page refresh, it adds the number of rolls to the previous roll.

On refresh, it outputs the stored value and then immediately logs undefined again and the loop continues as mentioned above.

```
    const [tenzies, setTenzies] = useState(false);

    let [rollCount, setRollCount] = useState(0);

    const [prevRollCount, setPrevRollCount] = useState(rollCount);

    const [storeRoll, setStoreRoll] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("die"))
    );
```

Actually using a useEffect() and storing the code to retrieve in a state. Didn't include a dependency array because that enabled the `storeRoll` to be updated after discovering a win. `tenzies` is updated in another `useEffect` to true on a win.

```
     useEffect(() => {
       setStoreRoll(localStorage.setItem("die", JSON.stringify(prevRollCount))
       ); 

         if (tenzies) {
           setStoreRoll(prevRollCount);
         }
     });
  
     // Updates the roll count back to zero when there is a win
     function updateRollCount() {
        setTenzies(false);
        setDice(allNewDice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]));
        setRollCount(0);
        setTime(0);

        if (prevRollCount !== rollCount) {
          setStoreRoll(prevRollCount);
        }
     }

     // Saves the state of the dice we held or do not want to change on roll
      function rollDice() {
        if (!tenzies) {
          setDice((prevValue) => {
            return prevValue.map((die, index) => {
              return die.isHeld
                ? { ...die }
                : (die = allNewDice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])[index]);
            });
          });      
         } 

        else {
          setTenzies(false);
          setDice(allNewDice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]));
        }

        // Updates state for the number of rolls
        setRollCount(prevValue => 
          prevValue + 1
        );

        setPrevRollCount(prevValue => prevValue + 1);

     }
```

`

What I basically want to do is that when a user wins a game and starts a new game, initialize a new state that helps store that value showing them their previous roll.

Here is the link to an updated [Sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-curran-sh2tlq?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: We can't address issues in code we can't see. Please [edit] the post to provide more details what exactly the issue is and to include a [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I have added some explanations on my issue.  I have also updated the Code Sandbox demo link to point to the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing undefined when console logging the prevRolls state right after setting it is due to React state updates being asynchronous. Setting state via setPrevRolls() will trigger a re-render, but the new state value won't be available immediately.

There are a couple ways to fix this:

1. Use the callback form of setState:

```
setPrevRolls(prevRollsFromLocalStorage, () => {
  console.log(prevRolls) // will have updated value
})
```

2. Use useEffect to run code after state has updated:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(prevRolls) 
}, [prevRolls])
```

3. Access prevRolls later after component re-renders, such as in rendered UI.

The issue is React hasn't finished updating prevRolls when you try to log it immediately after setting. Use a callback, useEffect, or access later in component lifecycle to get the updated value.

Identifying the asynchronous state update behavior as the root cause is key to solving issues like this in React.

Comment: Thanks. I would like you to please check my post again. I have updated and described the issue more detailed than before.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. It was because I was trying to get the value of storeRoll without checking whether it exists first.